# Unable to install gnome-shell-extensions due to unmet dependencies

Tags: gnome

When I try to install gnome-shell-extensions I get unmet dependencies error:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-shell-extensions : Depends: gnome-shell (< 3.6) but 3.6.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-shell-extensions
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-shell-extensions 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for gnome-shell-extensions
`